# maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object when printing method name

Tags: python

I was able to mimic result with very simple code:

```
class test:
    def t(self):
        return 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.t

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)

t = test()
print "%s" % t
```

I know the issue is `"%s" % self.t` missing the `()`

my question is, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you print `self.t`, it prints

```
<bound method test.t of XXX>
```

where `XXX` is the representation of `self`. But in your class `repr(self)` calls `str(self)`, which then tries to print `self.t` again. This keeps recursing like this.